# Flutter navigating MaterialApp children

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm fairly new to flutter and dart, I set up my app like so:

```
class MyExpensesApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyExpensesApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyExpensesApp> createState() => _MyExpensesAppState();
}

class _MyExpensesAppState extends State<MyExpensesApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'title',
      home: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and i have a FloatingAction button inside the `HomePage` which navigates to a different page when clicked

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        ....
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ExpensePage()))
        },
        tooltip: "add expense",
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but when navigation to the `ExpensePage` screen, it is not RTL, which means it is not a child of Directionality widget?
Am i just replacing the whole MaterialApp with `ExpensePage`?
How can i only replace the Directionality Child when navigating?
I don't need any intricate routing, as i only have those 2 pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put a Directionality widget above the Navigator (and hence above every page), you can use the [`builder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/builder.html) property in `MaterialApp`.

```dart
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'title',
      home: HomePage(),
      builder: (context, child) => Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          child: child!,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! what does the exclamation mark do in `child!`?

Comment: @Dimon `child` is nullable, but since you provided a `home` widget, that child will be a (non-null) Navigator.  The exclamation mark tells Dart that `child` isn't null, so it can be passed as the `child` parameter of the Directionality widget constructor.

Answer (score 0):

For the child page, you can use Scaffold as the root parent.
Then try with the same routing.

Comment: The child page 'HomePage' build method returns a Scaffold.. same for the 'ExpensePage'.

Comment: Only the initial page should have material app. And for the rest screen you can scaffold as parent or root widget